# How do I combine check all script and filtering?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JavaScript and jQuery, but have used HTML and CSS before. In any case, I appreciate the help. I have implemented the script discussed here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-jquery-to-manipulate-and-filter-data/ for filtering data and the one discussed here http://www.dustindiaz.com/check-one-check-all-javascript/ for a check one to check all script. The problem is, when I filter the list of items and then use the check all box, it is checking even the JS items that are hidden from the user due to filtering. Does this make sense?

I have been trying to figure out how to edit the check all script so that only items with the "visible" class (as added to visible checkboxes with the filtering script) are checked with the checkAll button. The original script had:

```
var checks = document.getElementsByName('del[]');
```

I was trying to do something like this (it wasn't working, of course):

```
var visiblechecks = $('input:del[]:checked.visible');
```

among other things.

Thank you! Also, if you have a recommended resource, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var visiblechecks = $('input[name="del[]"]:checked:visible');`

Comment: Many thanks! I ended up changing the above slightly - removing the "checked" part and adding it in a later point of the code. In any case, thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your selector just needs a bit of refinement. Try:

```
$(".myCheckAllSelector").change(function () {
    $("input[name='del[]']:visible").attr("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

This should set the checked attribute of all currently visible checkboxes with the name del[] to the checked status of the check all box. You simply need to update the check all selector appropriately to target your master checkbox element.

You don't necessarily "need" to add a visible class as there is a [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) filter you can use to make that determination for you. However, just change your selector from `input` to `input.visible` if you still wish to use the class and remove the `:visible` filter..